# IPv6 source address selection by ip rule and ip route

Tags: networking, ipv6, iproute

I am trying to setup a Linux firewall and VPN setup to allow a host to talk over WIFI or a VPN.
The firewall on the remote end of the VPN connection will allow packets on the VPN through, but not on over the WIFI, and this works.
On the remote machine, incoming packets I deal with using (sanitized):

```
# ip -4 rule add from <myblock> table <mytable>
# ip -4 route add to <remoteblock> src <myaddr> dev <vpn-dev> table <mytable>
# ip -6 rule add from <myblock> table <mytable>
# ip -6 route add to <remoteblock> src <myaddr> dev <vpn-dev> table <mytable>
```

This successfully deals with incoming connections and making them symmetric.  (i.e. packets received on the VPN are not replied to on WIFI and vice versa.)

For IPv4, I then add:

```
# ip -4 rule add from 0.0.0.0/32 table <mytable>
```

And outgoing packets route to my protected network over the VPN.

However, when I try:

```
# ip -6 rule add from ::/128 table <mytable>
```

it doesn't help.  Packets are sent from the WIFI's address.  What magic cookie needs to be invoked to make it work?  OR does IPv6 do something completely different?

**Edit**: I added:

```
# ip -6 route add not from <wifinet>/64 table <mytable>
```

and things work.  So there is an *as-yet-unspecified* address there, it just isn't `::`.  Any suggestions?

**Edit**: Well, I've been confusing myself (which is why I rolled back and then restored my last edit), but:
It turns out that either of:

```
# ip -6 route add not from 0000::/1 table <mytable>
# ip -6 route add not from 8000::/1 table <mytable>
```

works, but

```
# ip -6 route add not from 0000::/0 table <mytable>
```

does not, as it becomes "not from any".

It turns out that:

```
# ip -6 route add from 0000::/0 table <mytable>
```

Also seems to work...  Personally, I don't think it should (though I am not quite sure why).

It may help that my VPN and  are in FC00::/7 and the WIFI ins in 2000::/3,  Bit I do seem to need to force the `src` to force the proper use of the VPN.